# Apply CSS to PHP Date function

Tags: php, css, date

This might sound weird and might be very simple but my mind just isn't thinking properly right now.

I'm displaying the date with following format using **PHP Date** function

```
date('l, F jS Y, time());
```

Displays: **Wednesday, April 10th 2013**

How do I make **th** somehow a superscript without trying to extract the **th** from the returned string and applying **CSS** to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can split it into multiple parts:

```
$formatted = date('l, F j') . '<sup>' . date('S') . '</sup> ' . date('Y');
```

It's not particularly efficient, calling date so many times, but it's somewhat more reliable than a string operation.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer this over concatenation and several `date()` calls...

```
date('l, F j\<\s\u\p\>S\<\/\s\u\p\> Y', time());
```

Comment: works better, but I absolutely LOATHE code that suffers from "leaning toothpick" syndrome. I'll gladly suffer a bit of inefficiency to gain readability.

Comment: this works as well, thanks alot but i would rather use the splitting into multiple date calls since I want code to be more readable at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

```
<?php
echo date('l F j\<\s\u\p\ \s\t\y\l\e\=\c\o\l\o\r\:\r\e\d\;\> S\<\/\s\u\p\> Y', time()); 
?>
```

**DEMO**: **[HERE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dBPsFL)**